# Angularjs2 resolve all

Tags: angular

What I want to achieve is to make request to /session on application refresh, what's more - the problem is that I need to make it synchronous, application should wait for resolve and with that response I could either go to login page or leave user on current page.

Answer (score 1):

In JS there is no direct way to make asynchronous calls synchronous.

However, if you work with `Observables` (and I recommend you do) you can use a `flatMap` to combine two `Observables` where the second depends on the first.
Something like

```
Observable1.flatMap((resultOfObservable1) =>
{
   doSomethingWithResult()
}).subscribe(doSomethingWithFinalResult);
```

Without any code it's not really possible to answer in more detail.

Comment: I'm creating angualrJS 2 application and I'm pretty sure there must be mechanism for that kind of behaviour but I couldn't find anything like that in documentation. Chaining observables/promises is not the answer (I guess), thanks for your comment ! : )

Comment: You couldn't find it because there is no other way. Chaining Observables is the answer. Good luck.

Comment: Oki, could you tell me where should I implement something like that? Where's the place where I can put request to /session which will be fired up every time on browser refresh?